# Not retrieving all objects using Doctrine 2 querybuilder

Tags: join, doctrine-orm, zend-framework2, query-builder

I've made a query using querybuilder. It look likes:

```
//Create a Querybuilder
        $qb = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();

        //Foreach entity, check if it's a join and leftjoin it.
        //If there's no join, make it the select
        foreach($config['entities'] as $name => $entity)
        {
            //add new alias(ses) to select statement
            $qb->addSelect($entity['alias']);

            if(!isset($entity['join'])){
                $qb->from($entity['path'], $entity['alias']);
            } else {
                $qb->leftJoin($entity['join'], $entity['alias']);
            }
        }
           ->orWhere(':test IS NULL')
       ->setParameter('test', 'User\Entity\Address');

    //Make the query
    $query = $qb->getQuery();

    //Return the result
    return $query->getResult();
```

I've made my select and left join dynamically with a config file. So people can make own joins. But when i have (for example) users and addresses. It shows only users WITH addresses. Users without addresses are not show. When i've no join, all users show up. Has somebody an idea about it? I read something like i've to set a where clause and do something like:

```
->orWhere(':test IS NULL')
           ->setParameter('test', 'User\Entity\Address');
```

It doesn't work. How can i have joins AND show all the users also WITHOUT addresses?

Grtz

Answer (score 0):

I've a problem with my where clause. It had a "like" in it, where he wants to like the "street" (from addresses), to something. But when users didn't had a address, he can't like and so he don't show the whole user.